# Nuclear forces and Chiral Effective field Theory

Tags: nuclear-physics, effective-field-theory

I am new to this field "nuclear forces and Chiral Effective field Theory". 
while reading this paper http://arxiv.org/abs/nucl-th/0006014 . I have got few question:

1. How many different version of CD-Bonn potential exists? CD-Bonn 2000 potential is most updated and correct version?
2. CD-Bonn, Nijmegen and Argonne V18 are constructed using chiral effective field theory?

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few different versions of the Born potential. Most popular ones include the Bonn-A, B, C (with different strength for tensor force) and the Charge dependent Bonn (CD-Bonn) potential. CD-Bonn 2000 is the most recent one.

None of the three potentials you mentioned are chiral potential. They are based on meson exchange potential.